# Spaces within string search query cause search to return with no results

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to search a mySQL database and return the result with the maximum version however it always returns with no results when there is a space in the search.

I have tried using replace within the select MAX in the query however that just caused syntax errors.

```
SELECT document_versions.payload, document_versions.version 
FROM document_versions 
INNER JOIN documents ON documents.guid = document_versions.document_guid WHERE document_versions.title = @name 
AND documents.document_type_id = 35 
AND document_versions.version = 
(SELECT MAX(version) FROM document_versions WHERE title = @name)
```

I have also tried

```
SELECT document_versions.payload, document_versions.version 
FROM document_versions INNER JOIN documents ON documents.guid = document_versions.document_guid 
    WHERE REPLACE(document_versions.title,' ','') = 
    REPLACE(@name,' ','')
    AND documents.document_type_id = 35 
    AND document_versions.version = 
    SELECT MAX(version) FROM document_versions 
    WHERE REPLACE(title,' ','') = REPLACE(@name,' ',''))
```

Which also returns no results.

Comment: Sample data (showcasing your issue) with expected output would be really helpful. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried like this ?

```
SELECT document_versions.payload, document_versions.version 
FROM document_versions 
INNER JOIN documents ON documents.guid = document_versions.document_guid 
WHERE document_versions.title = @name 
AND documents.document_type_id = 35 
ORDER BY document_versions.version DESC LIMIT 1
```